# Get information of the video saved to photos album by URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avasset

I'm saving a video obtained from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` with `AVAsset` using `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` like below.

```
    NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"capture%d.mp4", _currentFile];
    NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_encoder finishWithCompletionHandler:^{
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                NSLog(@"save completed");
            }];
        }];
    });
```

However after saving the video I want to get the 'saved videos info' back like we get with following when using `UIImagePickerController`.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    NSLog(@"there");

    // Handle a movie capture
    NSString *type = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    NSURL *videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    //do things with that info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to save the video and add that video in custom album, and then inform where it has been saved.

```
 [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoInputUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Video could not be saved");
    }
    else{

            [library assetForURL:assetURL
                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                         // assign the photo to the album
                         [groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
                         NSLog(@"Added Successfully %@ to %@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename], albumName);
                         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video Saved to xyz Album."  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
                         [alert show];
                     }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                        NSLog(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }];
    }
}];
```

Hope this help you...:)